# How can I efficiently ship a Room database with my Android app?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I'm working on an Android app where you can play "Wordle". I want to be able to use it offline so I have a Room database including all the possible words (currently around 30MB in size). I want to ship that database with my app but I also want to be able to update DB in app updates (adding/removing entries). How can I do that in a efficient way?

My current database manager includes this function:

```
fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized(AppDatabase::class.java) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java, "words"
                )
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .createFromAsset("words.db")
                    .build()
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE!!
    }
```

From my understanding this code looks if there is a database and if not creates a new one from the file words.db file in the assets folder. In this process it copies the file into the working directory and then includes it just like a normal Room DB.
It seems to me that this process is not very efficient as the DB is copied ever time the process is terminated and the app is restarted. How would I do that more efficiently? And how could I still update the database with an app update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems to me that this process is not very efficient as the DB is copied ever time the process is terminated and the app is restarted

That is not what happens. It only copies the asset one time, if the database was not copied previously.

FWIW, I cover pre-populated databases and Room in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Room/pages/chap-package-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Room/).

> And how could I still update the database with an app update?

While Room can help detect and deal with *schema* updates, you are on your own for tracking *content* updates. So, you try something like:

- Have a Room entity that represents your database content version. That version could be represented as a date, a version number akin to `versionCode`, or something else.
- Have your pre-populated database have its version in the table associated with that entity.
- Have that same version identifier available to your Kotlin or Java code, such as via `BuildConfig`.
- After opening the database, use your DAO to query for the content version entity, and compare its value with the one in your Kotlin or Java code. If the one in your code is newer, this indicates that your user has an older database. In that case, you can close the database, delete the database file, then re-open the database. That will trigger Room to create a fresh copy out of the (newer) asset.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, which:-

- can be controlled directly according to the asset itself,
- will be more efficient than checking from within Room,

  - no need to access the database via Room, close it and do thw work, and the reopen the database (close and reopen being relatively resource intensive)
- will be less prone to complications should migrations be involved

could be to utilise a typically unused value that is similar to the user_version.

The user_version aka the database version is stored in the database files header (first 100 bytes of the file). The user_version is 4 bytes at an offset of 60 bytes.

At an offset of 68 bytes is the application_id which is also a 4 byte integer value. It is seldom used and thus can be used as a secondary version to indicate a change to the data, rather than the schema.

- see https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html

This has the advantage that rather than an entire wipe of the database that rows could be added or deleted but also keeping any updates to the actual data by the App.

**Demonstration**

Consider a relatively simply **word** table as per:-

```
const val DATABASE_VERSION = 10
const val DATABASE_NAME = "word.db"
const val ASSET_NAME = DATABASE_NAME
const val WORD_TABLE_NAME = "word"
const val WORD_TABLE_ID_COL = "word_id"
const val WORD_TABLE_WORD_COL = "word"
const val WORD_TABLE_LASTUSED_COL = "last_used"

@Entity(
    tableName = WORD_TABLE_NAME,
    indices = [
        Index(value = [WORD_TABLE_WORD_COL], unique = true)
    ]
)
data class Word(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = WORD_TABLE_ID_COL)
    val wordId: Long?=null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = WORD_TABLE_WORD_COL)
    val word: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = WORD_TABLE_LASTUSED_COL, defaultValue = "0")
    val usedCount: Long
)
```

So 3 columns

1. **wordId** (not needed but no waste as it aliases the normally hidden but present **rowid**)
2. **word** the actual word to be stored (with an index that makes it unique)
3. **usedCount**, this added to demonstrate updated data that should be retained

Now consider the first asset/pre-packaged database probably generated by an SQLite tool (Navicat for SQLite used for the demo).

Using the following SQL in the tool:-

```
/* 
    Code from Java(generated) in Android Studio, after the project has been compiled
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `word` (`word_id` INTEGER, `word` TEXT NOT NULL, `last_used` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, PRIMARY KEY(`word_id`))");
        db.execSQL("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `index_word_word` ON `word` (`word`)");
*/

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS word;
/* Copied from generated java (comment above) */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `word` (`word_id` INTEGER, `word` TEXT NOT NULL, `last_used` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, PRIMARY KEY(`word_id`));

INSERT INTO word (word) VALUES
    ('word1'),('word2'),('word3'),('word4') /* and so on */
;
/* Copied from generated java (comment above)
    left till after inserts as more efficient (not that is matters)
*/
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `index_word_word` ON `word` (`word`);
PRAGMA application_id;
PRAGMA application_id = 100;
PRAGMA application_id;
PRAGMA user_version;
PRAGMA user_version = 10;
PRAGMA user_version;

/*
    Second version adds more words increases the application id
*/

/*
INSERT INTO word (word) VALUES
    ('word6'),('word7'),('word8')
;
DELETE FROM word WHERE word = 'word3';
PRAGMA application_id;
PRAGMA application_id = 111;
PRAGMA application_id;
*/
```

- Note the last SQL is commented out and is used for the subsequent incarnation.
- Note the use of the `PRAGMA application_id` (and likewise user_version) without a value it retrieves the respective stored value. With a value it sets the respective stored value. So the above **sets the application_id to 100**.

After running the above then the **first incarnation** is:-

[image]

To demonstrate use of the data some `@Dao` annotated functions would be required. So:-

```
@Dao
interface WordDAO {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(word: Word)
    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun update(word: Word)
    @Query("SELECT * FROM ${WORD_TABLE_NAME}")
    fun getAllWords(): List<Word>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM ${WORD_TABLE_NAME} ORDER BY (random()) LIMIT 1")
    fun getRandomWordRow(): Word
    @Query("")
    @Transaction
    fun getARandomWordAndMarkItAsUsed(): Word {
        val rv = getRandomWordRow()
        update(Word(rv.wordId,rv.word,rv.usedCount + 1))
        return Word(rv.wordId,rv.word,rv.usedCount+1)
    }
}
```

- The assumption is that a random word would be selected for a game. However, for the sake of App updated data to be retained a count of the number of time s the word has been used is maintained.

  - note that assuming the update count, as per the returned usedCount, may be unwise but it reduces the code for the demo.

At this stage the `@Database` annotated class can be introduced (actually this was created prior so Room's exact requirements for the CREAT SQL could be copied (see comments in the SQL)). So:-

```
@Database(entities = [Word::class], version = DATABASE_VERSION, exportSchema = false)
abstract class WordDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getWordDAO(): WordDAO

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: WordDatabase? = null
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): WordDatabase {
            /* If the database exists then take control */
            if(PreRoomHandler.doesDatabaseExist(context, DATABASE_NAME)) {
                val assetAndActualDBValues = PreRoomHandler.getAssetAndActualDBValues(context,
                    DATABASE_NAME, ASSET_NAME)
                if (assetAndActualDBValues.assetApplicationId > assetAndActualDBValues.actualApplicationId) {
                    Log.d("DBINFO","APPLICATION ID INCREASED.")
                    PreRoomHandler.applyNewRowsFromAsset(context, DATABASE_NAME, ASSET_NAME,assetAndActualDBValues.assetApplicationId)
                }
            }
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(WordDatabase::class.java) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        WordDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME
                    )
                        .allowMainThreadQueries()
                        .createFromAsset(ASSET_NAME)
                        .addCallback(cb)
                        .build()
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE!!
        }
        /* Callback*/
        private val cb = object:   Callback() {
            override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onCreate(db)
                Log.d("DBCALLBACK","ONCREATE INVOKED. USER_VERSION is ${db.version}. DBPATH is ${db.path}")
            }

            override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onOpen(db)
                Log.d("DBCALLBACK","ONOPEN INVOKED. USER_VERSION is ${db.version}, DBPATH is ${db.path}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- This is simlilar to your class **BUT**:-

  - a) some stuff about **`PreRoomHandler`**, and
  - b) the addition of a call back (just to log in case debugging is required)

So Obviously the **`PreRoomHandler`** class comes into play. However, prior to that a class that is used to collect/store 4 values the asset's ***user_version*** and ***application_id*** and the same values from the actual database:-

```
/*
    Class for the SQLite Header values
        user_version (offset 60) and
        application_id (offset 68)
        for both the asset and the actual database
        as per https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html
 */
data class AssetAndActualDBValues(
    val assetUser: Int,
    val assetApplicationId: Int,
    val actualUser: Int,
    val actualApplicationId: Int
)
```

The **`PreRoomHandler`** handles comparing the asset with the actual database and also changes to be applied from the asset to the actual database. It is:-

```
abstract class PreRoomHandler {
    companion object {
        /* SQLite header offset values */
        private val USER_VERSION_OFFSET: Int=60
        private val APPLICATION_ID_OFFSET: Int=68
        private val VLEN=4

        fun doesDatabaseExist(context: Context, databaseName: String): Boolean {
            val rv = context.getDatabasePath(databaseName).exists()
            Log.d("DBPRH","ACTUAL DATABASE EXISTS = ${rv}")
            return rv
        }

        fun getAssetAndActualDBValues(context: Context, databaseName: String, assetName: String): AssetAndActualDBValues {
            val assetInputStream = context.assets.open(assetName)
            val actualInputStream = context.getDatabasePath(databaseName).inputStream()


            val asset_uv: ByteArray=byteArrayOf(0,0,0,0)
            val asset_ai: ByteArray=byteArrayOf(0,0,0,0)
            val actual_uv: ByteArray=byteArrayOf(0,0,0,0)
            val actual_ai: ByteArray=byteArrayOf(0,0,0,0)

            assetInputStream.skip((USER_VERSION_OFFSET).toLong())
            assetInputStream.read(asset_uv,0, VLEN)
            assetInputStream.skip(((APPLICATION_ID_OFFSET-(USER_VERSION_OFFSET+VLEN))).toLong())
            assetInputStream.read(asset_ai, 0, VLEN)
            assetInputStream.close()

            actualInputStream.skip((USER_VERSION_OFFSET).toLong())
            actualInputStream.read(actual_uv, 0, VLEN)
            actualInputStream.skip((APPLICATION_ID_OFFSET-(USER_VERSION_OFFSET+VLEN)).toLong())
            actualInputStream.read(actual_ai, 0, VLEN)
            actualInputStream.close()

            val rv = AssetAndActualDBValues(
                assetUser = getIntFromByteArray(asset_uv),
                assetApplicationId = getIntFromByteArray(asset_ai),
                actualUser = getIntFromByteArray(actual_uv),
                actualApplicationId = getIntFromByteArray(actual_ai)
            )
            Log.d("DBPRH","VALUES OBTAINED are:-" +
                    "\n\tASSET USER VERSION is ${rv.assetUser}" +
                    "\n\tACTUAL USER VERSION is ${rv.actualUser}" +
                    "\n\tASSET APPLICATION ID is ${rv.assetApplicationId}" +
                    "\n\tACTUAL APPLICATION ID is ${rv.actualApplicationId}"
            )
            return rv
        }

        fun applyNewRowsFromAsset(context: Context, databaseName: String, assetName: String, newApplicationId: Int) {
            val temp_asset_dbname = assetName + "_temp"
            val assetSchema = "asset"
            val actualDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(databaseName).path,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
            val asset_is = context.assets.open(assetName)
            val temp_asset_db_os = context.getDatabasePath(temp_asset_dbname).outputStream()
            asset_is.copyTo(temp_asset_db_os)
            actualDB.beginTransaction()
            actualDB.execSQL(" ATTACH DATABASE '${context.getDatabasePath(temp_asset_dbname).path}' AS ${assetSchema}")
            actualDB.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ${WORD_TABLE_NAME} SELECT * FROM ${assetSchema}.${WORD_TABLE_NAME}")
            actualDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM ${WORD_TABLE_NAME} " +
                    "WHERE ${WORD_TABLE_WORD_COL} " +
                    "NOT IN(SELECT ${WORD_TABLE_WORD_COL} FROM ${assetSchema}.${WORD_TABLE_WORD_COL})")
            actualDB.setTransactionSuccessful()
            actualDB.endTransaction()
            actualDB.execSQL("DETACH DATABASE ${assetSchema}")
            File(temp_asset_dbname).delete()
            actualDB.execSQL("PRAGMA application_id = ${newApplicationId}")
            actualDB.close()
        }

        /* Get an Int value from a 4 byte ByteArray */
        private fun getIntFromByteArray(byteArray: ByteArray?, badValueIndicator: Int=0): Int {
            if ((byteArray == null) || (byteArray.size != VLEN)) return badValueIndicator
            return (byteArray[0].toInt() and 0xff shl 24) or
                    (byteArray[1].toInt() and 0xff shl 16) or
                    (byteArray[2].toInt() and 0xff shl 8) or
                    (byteArray[3].toInt() and 0xff)
        }
    }
}
```

- the **`doesDatabaseExist`** function checks to see if the database exists

  - the assumption is that the recommended storage location is in the databases folder (this assumption is made throughout).
  - this function would have a very small impact, it is just checking that the file exists.

If the file does not exist (a new install) then nothing will need to be done. Room will handle the copy of the current asset.

If the database does exist then the **`getAssetAndActualDBValues`** function is used  to extract the 4 values (application_id and user_version * 2) from the respective header (asset and actual database).

- the overhead of this check should also be minimal.

The **`getIntFromByteArray`** function just converts the 4 bytes into an Int.

The **`applyNewRowsFromAsset`** is called/invoked if the application_id of the asset is greater then the application_id of the actual database.

This creates a working copy of the asset in the databases folder. The actual database is opened using the SQLiteDatabase API the working copy of the asset is attached to the actual database. Then:-

1. All rows from the asset are copied to the actual database BUT due to the primary key/ unique word column and `OR IGNORE` ONLY NEW ROWS *(or rows that have been deleted)* will be copied into the actual database. This the **usedCount** value will be retained.
2. Rows are deleted from the actual database IF they do not have a corresponding row in the working copy of the asset.

   1. NOTE that this would delete rows added via the app (see wordx later as an example)

      1. An additional column flagging user v asset could be used to circumvent deletion of user added rows.

After the changes the transaction is marked as successful (so not to be rolled back) and the transaction ended. The working file/database is detached from the actual database and the new application_id is applied. The actual database is then closed and function ends, so Room then gets control.

A drawback as such is that the actual database is opened when an instance is requested/constructed not until a request to open the database is made.

For testing/demonstrating the following activity code:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: WordDatabase
    lateinit var dao: WordDAO
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = WordDatabase.getDatabase(this)
        dao = db.getWordDAO()
        for (w in dao.getAllWords()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO_ALL","Word is ${w.word} ID is ${w.wordId} Used = ${w.usedCount}")
        }
        for (i in 1..5) {
            val currentWord = dao.getARandomWordAndMarkItAsUsed()
            Log.d("DBINFO_RND","Word is ${currentWord.word} ID is ${currentWord.wordId} Used = ${currentWord.usedCount}")
        }
        dao.insert(Word(word ="wordx", usedCount = -10))
    }
}
```

**Running the above**

First 2 databases were created

1. with an application_id of **100** with words 1-4.
2. a second with an application_id of 111 with:-

   1. word3 deleted
   2. words 5-8 added (see comments in the SQL)

The files, ensuring that there were no files of the same name but suffixed with -wal or -shm (i.e. the database have been fully closed) wre then copied into the assets folder:-

[image]

- the actual **word.db** asset is created/overwritten by the applicable other file.

**Run 1 (Fresh install)**

File **word_first.db** is copied (overwriting if necessary) **word.db** and the App run, The log includes:-

```
2024-01-07 10:53:26.625 D/DBPRH: ACTUAL DATABASE EXISTS = false
2024-01-07 10:53:26.773 D/DBCALLBACK: ONOPEN INVOKED. USER_VERSION is 10, DBPATH is /data/user/0/a.a.so77769872kotlinroomupdatingprepopulated/databases/word.db
2024-01-07 10:53:26.777 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word1 ID is 1 Used = 0
2024-01-07 10:53:26.777 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word2 ID is 2 Used = 0
2024-01-07 10:53:26.777 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word3 ID is 3 Used = 0
2024-01-07 10:53:26.777 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word4 ID is 4 Used = 0


2024-01-07 10:53:26.781 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word3 ID is 3 Used = 1
2024-01-07 10:53:26.784 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word1 ID is 1 Used = 1
2024-01-07 10:53:26.787 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word2 ID is 2 Used = 1
2024-01-07 10:53:26.791 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word2 ID is 2 Used = 2
2024-01-07 10:53:26.799 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word3 ID is 3 Used = 2
```

**Run 2 (nothing changed)**

```
2024-01-07 10:56:54.497 D/DBPRH: ACTUAL DATABASE EXISTS = true
2024-01-07 10:56:54.498 D/DBPRH: VALUES OBTAINED are:-
        ASSET USER VERSION is 10
        ACTUAL USER VERSION is 10
        ASSET APPLICATION ID is 100
        ACTUAL APPLICATION ID is 100
2024-01-07 10:56:54.551 D/DBCALLBACK: ONOPEN INVOKED. USER_VERSION is 10, DBPATH is /data/user/0/a.a.so77769872kotlinroomupdatingprepopulated/databases/word.db
2024-01-07 10:56:54.553 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word1 ID is 1 Used = 1
2024-01-07 10:56:54.554 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word2 ID is 2 Used = 2
2024-01-07 10:56:54.554 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word3 ID is 3 Used = 2
2024-01-07 10:56:54.554 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word4 ID is 4 Used = 0
2024-01-07 10:56:54.554 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is wordx ID is 5 Used = -10

2024-01-07 10:56:54.556 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word3 ID is 3 Used = 3
2024-01-07 10:56:54.571 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word3 ID is 3 Used = 4
2024-01-07 10:56:54.575 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is wordx ID is 5 Used = -9
2024-01-07 10:56:54.579 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word4 ID is 4 Used = 1
2024-01-07 10:56:54.585 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word4 ID is 4 Used = 2
```

- the database exists so the versions/values are extracted
- wordx now exits as it was added in the previous run

**Run 3 (asset overwitten using word_second.db file)**

```
2024-01-07 11:01:35.426  D/DBPRH: ACTUAL DATABASE EXISTS = true
2024-01-07 11:01:35.427  D/DBPRH: VALUES OBTAINED are:-
        ASSET USER VERSION is 10
        ACTUAL USER VERSION is 10
        ASSET APPLICATION ID is 111
        ACTUAL APPLICATION ID is 100
2024-01-07 11:01:35.427  D/DBINFO: APPLICATION ID INCREASED.
2024-01-07 11:01:35.537  D/DBCALLBACK: ONOPEN INVOKED. USER_VERSION is 10, DBPATH is /data/user/0/a.a.so77769872kotlinroomupdatingprepopulated/databases/word.db
2024-01-07 11:01:35.541  D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word1 ID is 1 Used = 1
2024-01-07 11:01:35.541  D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word2 ID is 2 Used = 2
2024-01-07 11:01:35.541  D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word4 ID is 4 Used = 2
2024-01-07 11:01:35.541  D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word6 ID is 6 Used = 0
2024-01-07 11:01:35.541  D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word7 ID is 7 Used = 0
2024-01-07 11:01:35.541  D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word8 ID is 8 Used = 0
2024-01-07 11:01:35.548  D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word6 ID is 6 Used = 1
2024-01-07 11:01:35.562  D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word7 ID is 7 Used = 1
2024-01-07 11:01:35.570  D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word7 ID is 7 Used = 2
2024-01-07 11:01:35.578  D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word4 ID is 4 Used = 3
2024-01-07 11:01:35.583  D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word6 ID is 6 Used = 2
```

- application_id has been increased
- word3 has been deleted as it was not in the new asset
- word6,7  and 8 have been added.
- wordx has been lost (but will now exist due to the insert)

**Run 4 (nothing changed)**

```
2024-01-07 11:08:35.729 D/DBPRH: ACTUAL DATABASE EXISTS = true
2024-01-07 11:08:35.730 D/DBPRH: VALUES OBTAINED are:-
        ASSET USER VERSION is 10
        ACTUAL USER VERSION is 10
        ASSET APPLICATION ID is 111
        ACTUAL APPLICATION ID is 111
2024-01-07 11:08:35.795 D/DBCALLBACK: ONOPEN INVOKED. USER_VERSION is 10, DBPATH is /data/user/0/a.a.so77769872kotlinroomupdatingprepopulated/databases/word.db
2024-01-07 11:08:35.798 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word1 ID is 1 Used = 1
2024-01-07 11:08:35.798 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word2 ID is 2 Used = 2
2024-01-07 11:08:35.798 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word4 ID is 4 Used = 3
2024-01-07 11:08:35.798 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word6 ID is 6 Used = 2
2024-01-07 11:08:35.798 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word7 ID is 7 Used = 2
2024-01-07 11:08:35.799 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word8 ID is 8 Used = 0
2024-01-07 11:08:35.799 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is wordx ID is 9 Used = -10
2024-01-07 11:08:35.802 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word6 ID is 6 Used = 3
2024-01-07 11:08:35.820 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is wordx ID is 9 Used = -9
2024-01-07 11:08:35.824 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is wordx ID is 9 Used = -8
2024-01-07 11:08:35.826 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word7 ID is 7 Used = 3
2024-01-07 11:08:35.831 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word1 ID is 1 Used = 2
```

- Used Counts increased and wordx now exists

**Run 5 (new install asset as second)**

```
2024-01-07 11:12:46.120 D/DBPRH: ACTUAL DATABASE EXISTS = false
2024-01-07 11:12:46.249 D/DBCALLBACK: ONOPEN INVOKED. USER_VERSION is 10, DBPATH is /data/user/0/a.a.so77769872kotlinroomupdatingprepopulated/databases/word.db
2024-01-07 11:12:46.252 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word1 ID is 1 Used = 0
2024-01-07 11:12:46.253 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word2 ID is 2 Used = 0
2024-01-07 11:12:46.253 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word4 ID is 4 Used = 0
2024-01-07 11:12:46.253 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word5 ID is 5 Used = 0
2024-01-07 11:12:46.253 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word6 ID is 6 Used = 0
2024-01-07 11:12:46.253 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word7 ID is 7 Used = 0
2024-01-07 11:12:46.253 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word8 ID is 8 Used = 0
2024-01-07 11:12:46.257 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word2 ID is 2 Used = 1
2024-01-07 11:12:46.260 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word7 ID is 7 Used = 1
2024-01-07 11:12:46.263 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word5 ID is 5 Used = 1
2024-01-07 11:12:46.269 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word6 ID is 6 Used = 1
2024-01-07 11:12:46.274 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word1 ID is 1 Used = 1
```

- second version (word3 missing as expected)

**Migrations**

In short as the application of updates is undertaken prior to Room accessing the database the database, whether changed or not according to a new `application_id`, can be passed to Room after; this caters for the migration being handled by Room (Auto or Manual Migration)

As an example, consider the following changes to the above code:-

- a change to the database version:-

  - `const val DATABASE_VERSION = 11/*<<<<<<<<<< FROM 10 TO 11 */`
- a new constant for a new column:-

  - const val WORD_TABLE_OTHER_COL = "other" /*<<<<<< ADDED for Miragtion */
- The new val aka the new column:-

  - `/* <<<<< MIGRATION NEW COLUMN */ @ColumnInfo(name = WORD_TABLE_OTHER_COL, defaultValue = "unset") val other: String`
- a modified `getARandomWordAndMarkItAsUsed` function:-

  - `//update(Word(rv.wordId,rv.word,rv.usedCount + 1)) update(Word(rv.wordId,rv.word,rv.usedCount+1,rv.other)) /* <<<< changed for Mig10to11 */ //return Word(rv.wordId,rv.word,rv.usedCount+1) return (Word(rv.wordId,rv.word,rv.usedCount+1,rv.other)) /* <<<< changed for Mig10to11 */`
- the introduction of the migration:-

  - `/* Added for Migration 10 to 11 */ .addMigrations( mig10_to_11() )`
- the needless insert of wordx (optional):-

  - `//dao.insert(Word(word ="wordx", usedCount = -10))`
- for the log to include the **other** column:-

  - `/* Added for Migration 10 to 11 */ + "Other is ${currentWord.other}")`

finally the actual `mig10to11` function:-

```
    /* <<<< ADDED for Mig10to11 */
    private fun mig10_to_11() =  Migration(10,11) {
        val suffix = "_mig10to11"
        it.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${WORD_TABLE_NAME}${suffix}")
        it.execSQL("ALTER TABLE ${WORD_TABLE_NAME} RENAME TO ${WORD_TABLE_NAME}${suffix}")
        /* SQL as copied from createAllTables function/method of the java(generated) class that is
            the same name as the @Database annotated class suffixed with _Impl
         */
        it.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `word` (`word_id` INTEGER, `word` TEXT NOT NULL, `last_used` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `other` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unset', PRIMARY KEY(`word_id`))")
        /* Populate the new table from the original (in this case setting the other column to be the value "setup")*/
        it.execSQL("INSERT INTO ${WORD_TABLE_NAME} " +
                "(${WORD_TABLE_ID_COL},${WORD_TABLE_WORD_COL},${WORD_TABLE_LASTUSED_COL},${WORD_TABLE_OTHER_COL})" +
                " SELECT ${WORD_TABLE_ID_COL},${WORD_TABLE_WORD_COL},${WORD_TABLE_LASTUSED_COL},'setup' FROM ${WORD_TABLE_NAME}${suffix}")
        /* Create the index that enforces a UNIQUE constraint on the word column (again SQL copied from createAllTables function/method) */
        /* DROP the original index, index name copied from SQL in generated java  */
        it.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS `index_word_word`")
        it.execSQL("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `index_word_word` ON `word` (`word`)")
        it.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${WORD_TABLE_NAME}${suffix}")
    }
```

- in this case the asset should be be changed to version 11 as being version 10 will cause the migration to be undertaken upon a new install.

When run as a new install, the log includes:-

```
2024-01-09 12:11:25.733 D/DBPRH: ACTUAL DATABASE EXISTS = false
2024-01-09 12:11:25.889 D/DBCALLBACK: ONOPEN INVOKED. USER_VERSION is 11, DBPATH is /data/user/0/a.a.so77769872kotlinroomupdatingprepopulated/databases/word.db
2024-01-09 12:11:25.892 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word1 ID is 1 Used = 0
2024-01-09 12:11:25.892 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word2 ID is 2 Used = 0
2024-01-09 12:11:25.892 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word4 ID is 4 Used = 0
2024-01-09 12:11:25.892 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word5 ID is 5 Used = 0
2024-01-09 12:11:25.892 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word6 ID is 6 Used = 0
2024-01-09 12:11:25.892 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word7 ID is 7 Used = 0
2024-01-09 12:11:25.892 D/DBINFO_ALL: Word is word8 ID is 8 Used = 0
2024-01-09 12:11:25.901 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word2 ID is 2 Used = 1 Other is setup
2024-01-09 12:11:25.905 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word4 ID is 4 Used = 1 Other is setup
2024-01-09 12:11:25.909 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word1 ID is 1 Used = 1 Other is setup
2024-01-09 12:11:25.912 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word4 ID is 4 Used = 2 Other is setup
2024-01-09 12:11:25.913 D/DBINFO_RND: Word is word7 ID is 7 Used = 1 Other is setup
```

- ***of course as there are other permutations of handling migrations (changes to the schema and or the change to data) and it may be best to let the Pre-Room handler or changes to the asset itself handle these along with the applicable changes to the user_version and or application_id***